# JDK version mismatch on OSX

Tags: macos, java, jdk

I've been developing in Java on OSX without issue for a couple of issues.  Yesterday, I started getting weird compiler crashes (NPEs deep in javac).

I installed JDK 1.8.0_101, but javac is reporting itself as 1.8.0_20.

```
$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac

$ ls -l /usr/bin/javac
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 20 Sep 15:16 /usr/bin/javac -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac

$ /usr/libexec/java_home 1.8
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

So everything's looking all awesome, but then:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_20
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing it to pick up the wrong version?  I've tried removing all the JVMs and reinstalling, and rebooting, and all that.

**Edit**

Even running javac from the target of the symlink reports the wrong version.  I've also confirmed that the md5 sum of /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
 matches that of a healthy install.

Comment: Don't you have `javac` in the `hash` command output?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.  hash says `javac=/usr/bin/javac`.  But even running javac from the symlink target reports the wrong version.

Comment: `which` does not take into account bash command hashing thus it is not a good way to test. Anyway in your case it seems you are running the same executable, so it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. List all files using `ls`.

There should be two folders `jdk1.8.0_101.jdk` and `jdk1.8.0_20.jdk`.
Enter `sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_20.jdk`.

Now check java -version and javac -version ,should be the same.